# why onViewattachedFromWindow() and onViewDetachedFromWindow() are invoked automatically every 5 minute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I use `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager(vertical)` to display a group of data.

I want to be notified when `RecyclerView` item is scrolled out of screen.

I have overridden:

```
onViewattachedFromWindow()
```

and

```
onViewDetachedFromWindow()
```

It works fine. `onViewattachedFromWindow()` will be invoked every-time an item getting into screen. `onViewDetachedFromWindow()` will be invoked every-time an item getting out of screen.

But

`onViewattachedFromWindow()` and `onViewDetachedFromWindow()` will be invoked automatically **every 5 minutes** even the whole `RecyclerView` is not scrolling.

Why would it happen? How can i fix it?

Comment: Probably after 5 mins your device gets to sleep?

Comment: the screen is not sleeping.sometime it will happen every 5 seconds.if the 5th item is the last visible item,the 6th to 8th item will be attached to window and immediately be detched from window